# Logging rootState and all mutations that have taken place in the mounted hook of a component?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a message component that will display an errorMessage whenever something goes wrong in my app. I would like to log to my Backend the complete vueX state obj and all mutations that have taken place whenever this happens, wondering if it can be done in  the mounted hook of the error component.

```
export default {
  name: 'Error',
  components: { PageHeader },
  mounted() {
    debugger
    console.log('rootState and all prior vueX mutations' ....????); 
  },
  methods: {
}
```

Comment: What about `this.$store.state`?

Comment: that does seem to get the rootState thanks

Answer (score 0):

- Get rootState: `this.$store.state`
- Get Vuex mutation lists array: `this.$store._mutations`

```js
export default {
  name: 'Error',
  components: { PageHeader },
  mounted() {
    console.log('rootState: ', this.$store.state);
    console.log('Vuex mutations: ', this.$store._mutations);
  },
  methods: {
}
```

Comment: it seems that gets a list of mututations rather than all mutations that have currently taken place